# install qtSerialPort library

Tags: 12.04, compiling, qt, make

I want to install qtserialport in precise1-Ubuntu.  I got the source directory using git. next I download lib-qt4-dev and qmake. I ran qmake. it works fine. 
but, make fails with the following error:

```
    cd src/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/src'
cd serialport/ && make -f Makefile 
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/src/serialport'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/src/serialport'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/src'
cd examples/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/examples'
cd cenumerator/ && make -f Makefile 
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/examples/cenumerator'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o cenumerator main.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
main.o: In function `QList<QSerialPortInfo>::free(QListData::Data*) [clone .isra.1]':
main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
main.o: In function `QList<QSerialPortInfo>::detach_helper(int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5QListI15QSerialPortInfoE13detach_helperEi[QList<QSerialPortInfo>::detach_helper(int)]+0x68): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::QSerialPortInfo(QSerialPortInfo const&)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5QListI15QSerialPortInfoE13detach_helperEi[QList<QSerialPortInfo>::detach_helper(int)]+0xc3): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5e): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10f): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::isBusy() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16b): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::hasProductIdentifier() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1bb): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::hasVendorIdentifier() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x212): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::manufacturer() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24a): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::description() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x282): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::systemLocation() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ba): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::portName() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x644): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::productIdentifier() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x674): undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::vendorIdentifier() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cenumerator] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/examples/cenumerator'
make[1]: *** [sub-cenumerator-make_default-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/saman/5.0.1/serialPortSrc/qtserialport/examples'
make: *** [sub-examples-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

although make fails, I can now include qtserialport header to my project. and about the failure, I checked main.cpp, it includes serialPortSrcInfo.so, this .so file has already been generated when qmake was called. how can I fix the problem?

Comment: libqt  is on 5 now. Are you sure you want to develop using a legacy api? That is probably why you cant find it on the preconfigured PPAs.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is based on Qt5+.
I am using Qtserial in my project (pilotnavigator). My QTSDK 5+ is installed locally (not via apt). These are the instructions.

- Copy qtplayground-qtserialport folder into a local folder (preferably where your Qt projects are). Example: `~/yourqtprojectfolder/pilotnavigator/qtplayground-qtserialport`
- Create a build folder at the same level called qtplayground-qtserialport-build in pilotnavigator folder. Example: `~/yourqtprojectfolder/pilotnavigator/qtplayground-qtserialport-build`

Find out where qmake lives. Normaly it is located in your Qt5 folder, probably ~/Qt5x.x.x/5.x.x/gcc_64/bin

Open a Linux Terminal\

cd to the qtplayground-qtserialport-build folder. Example `cd ~/yourqtprojectfolder/pilotnavigator/qtplayground-qtserialport-build`

run qmake. Example:

```
~/Qt5x.x.x/5.x.x/gcc_64/bin/qmake ~/yourqtprojectfolder/pilotnavigator/qtplayground-qtserialport/qtserialport.pro
make
```

(If you get an error concerning missing file libudev.h, you need to install the libudev-dev library, e.g. `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev`)

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: I believe it is based od qt4. OP needs libqt5 see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtserialport-opensource-src). @Sam Follow the link and copy the name of the package. Do  apt install on that package. Has the lib along with needed development dependencies. Building for a legacy target, you cant be sure which specs (functions) will be deprecated or possibly removed come November. maybe none at all, but maybe not (Maybe so??... Anyway). That is the risk you take when using outdated software. Furthermore, I doubt many deployment targets will let you release on the stable track w qt4.